# Эффективно пройтись только по некоторым элементам большого массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть некоторый массив.

```
vector<T> arr;
```

Нужно много раз проходить по некоторым элементам массива.

```
for(T i:arr)
if(isneed(i))
//...
```

Можно создать массив номеров требуемых элементов.
Но часто массив требуемых элементов изменяется и надо будет каждый раз пересобирать массив.

Можно отслеживать изменения списка нужных элементов по типу: элемент номер Х нужен/ненужен.

В исходном векторе переставлять элементы нельзя.

Можно использовать unordered_set но будет ли это рационально? 
Как сделать чтобы проход по элементам проходил как можно быстрее?

Comment: Просто по порядку величины - сколько элементов всего? Сколько приходится обходить? При этой "пересборке" элементы хотя бы остаются на своих местах? :) Что вам вообще дает `unordered_set`, если вы все равно вынуждены обходить **все** элементы, выбирая нужные?

Comment: Будет рационально или нет, вы можете выяснить сами, измерив время на **ваших** данных. Какой будет результат с вашими размерами массивов и времени вычисления `isneed`, мы сказать заранее не можем (да и никто, наверное).

Comment: примерный размер массива от 100 до 100000
нужных элементов 100-10000

Comment: массив требуется обойти не 1 а много раз при этом нужные элементы постепенно меняются

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков: Давайте я повторюсь: данных, которые вы привели, недостаточно, чтобы однозначно ответить, какой из способов быстрее. Проще всего выяснить то, какой из способов быстрее, вам самому, потому что только у вас есть нужные функции и типы данных.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы все равно будете проверять весь массив - то лучше вектор, в нем меньше оверхеда, будет быстрее работать.

Если можно как-то отслеживать изменения списка нужных - то берем вектор, нужные храним в начале, за ними ненужные. Как только происходит изменение списка нужных - переносим соответствующий элемент в нужную часть. Тогда при переборе как только встречаем ненужный элемент - это началась часть ненужных, и перебирать больше не надо.

Comment: Отслеживать можно по типу: элемент номер Х нужен/ненужен. В исходном векторе переставлять элементы нельзя. Можно попытаться вектор указателей но как обработать сообщение типа: "X ненужен" ?